# Reorder from admin to different store

Tags: admin, orders

Does anyone know how I can change the admin reordering so that either an order that is reordered automatically gets assigned to a different site or allows the operator to change the site the reorder is made from?  Basically we are closing a site down soon (it won't be deleted as that would get rid of old orders) and need to be able to allow reordering to continue working.

Comment: "it won't be deleted as that would get rid of old orders" - have you checked that for sure?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to rewrite the `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create::initFromOrder()` method because it propagates the original order's `store_id` value to the session, which is then used for subordinate actions:

```
public function initFromOrder(Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order)
{
    //...
    $this->getSession()->setStoreId($order->getStoreId());
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been wondering how to achieve the same thing.
I need to be able to assign an order to any website.

To easily do so, I just forked the file :

```
/app/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Sales/Order/Create.php
```

Then, based on the comment from Benmarks, I just commented out the line :

```
//$this->getSession()->setStoreId($order->getStoreId());
```

Doing this will NOT fill the storeId when duplicating an order, and therefore, It will trigger a Store Selector, so you can pick the store you want to create the order into.

Sorcy